# Why jQuery won't work on rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've done this command

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

Now, loaded jQuery won't be started when page is loaded:(
It used to work fine before precompiling...

What could be the possible reason?

**assets/javascripts/refresh_count.js**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        refreshPartialMail();
    });


    function refreshPartialMail() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/messages/refresh_part",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
      });
    }
```

**view**

```
...
<%= javascript_include_tag 'refresh_count' %>
...
```

**generated HTML**

```
<script src="/assets/refresh_count-0cdf67811wb7eavf438be9c8b8cc932bf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**the content of "/assets/refresh_count-0cdf67811wb7eavf438be9c8b8cc932bf.js"**

```
function refreshPartialMail(){$.ajax({url:"/messages/refresh_part",type:"GET",dataType:"script"})}jQuery(document).ready(function(){refreshPartialMail()});
```

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

It's also saying this when executing `precompile` does this matter???

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /var/www/html/sampleapp/Rakefile:7)
```

Comment: are you using `prototype` & `jQuery` both, if so replace `$` with `jQuery` like `$.ajax` to `jQuery.ajax` beacuase sometimes it conflicts with prototype

Comment: @Sali Thanks for reply:) I'm not using `prototype`

Answer (score 3):

I am using jquery in my project also and it works fine

on production also

Here is my application.js content

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require tinymce
//= require_tree .
```

I think adding **//= require_tree .** may solve problem pls try it once and reply....

Comment: Hey one quick suggestion if you are using firefox try firebug and check console if any errors or conflicts are there ......

Comment: I checked it on FireFox's web console. Before, I could see javascript was being called in background. But now, nothing appears in web console:(

Comment: I doubt it because of dependencies of gems or something... I did `bundle install --path=vendor/plugins` does this matter?

Comment: Let me know one thing does app works fine on development mode or after precompiling even on developement mode it doesnt work

Comment: I've found it!!! I was right I replaced whole app with the one before I've done `bundle install --path=vendor/plugins`. Then I did `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`. Now jQuery works fine!! This is so weird!!